# how to use generic webhook + git parameter

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

I have a jenkins job that uses the git parameters plugin. One of the parameters is the branch name, and it selects from a list. Works great. Note that the branch name it sets begins with a '/' character, so branch "foo2/bar" comes out as "/foo2/bar".

[image: git parameter branch]

Then I wanted to add a generic webhook to process a github app event, and automagically start a build. The generic webhook plugin lets you pull elements from the pull_request event payload using JSONPath. So '$.pull_request.head.ref' gets the branch name. This branch does NOT have a leading slash.

[image]

The problem is that when I need to put a "branch specifier" in the git setup. If I use just '${branch}', then it fails when kicked off manually because rev-parse does not like refs that begin with a '/'. If I try 'refs/heads$branch', it fails from the webhook because heads$branch doesn't evaluate to a real branch name. Same with 'refs/heads/$branch': double slashes are rejected. JSONPath doesn't allow adding any characters and the rest of it is just filters.

[image]

How do I solve this conundrum?

I would like to avoid creating multiple jobs to handle this, since there are a lot of jobs and it would explode the jenkins configuration.

jenkins: 2.303.1, git parameter plugin 0.9.13, generic webhook plugin 1.74.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it's not documented but examples showed the way.
There is a 'branch filter' setting, which takes a regex. I thought this was just a match/nomatch test, but if you use '()', You can specify which part of the string to keep.  Setting it to something like 'origin/(.*)' fixed the issue.
[image]